# How to modify the appearance of auth related flash messages?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, view, cakephp-3.0

I am having no luck trying to change the Flash Element on the AuthError from default to error?

I was just trying to see if I can change it, but now its driving me up the wall as I can not seem to change it?

This is how I have loaded my Auth in the AppController,

```
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that? -2',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'Login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'LoginPage'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'HomePage'
        ]
    ]);
```

So when I go to a not allowed page, it displays the authError message but using whatever class/id's are in the `Element/Flash/default.ctp` I wanted to change it to just use the same as the `error.cpt`

I have debugged the Auth Component, there was a 'flash' setting, tried setting that, but it did not work?

So how do I change the authError to use a different Flash Layout?

Thanks,

Comment: When you tried something, please always show what that was, so people can tell you whether you did something wrong, rather than having to explain everything in the hope that they don't repeat what you've already tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've figured, auth messages are using the `default.ctp` element by default, and that it's possible to configure the flash element when rendering it directly. To affect this globally, you can configure the component instead.

If all you want to do is to change the classname, then you can use the `class` parameter in the `flash` configuration options `params` setting:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    // ...
    'flash' => [
        'params' => [
            'class' => 'some-custom-class'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

If you want to use a different element, for example the `error.ctp` one, just use the `element` setting to specify its name

```
    'flash' => [
        'element' => 'error'
    ]
```

See also **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Configuration Options](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options)**

Comment: Thanks, thats better :) That works! - I tried <code>'flash' => ['error'] </code>, <code>'flashElement' => ['error'] </code> but just not the option you just gave me! You know, I was all over the docs (I think that CakePHP has quick good ones) But I must have missed that. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got a solution.

It seems that when I print `$this->Flash->render('auth');`

I need to change it at this point to `$this->Flash->render('auth',['element' => 'error']);`

But if anyone knows any better ways to do this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 3 you can define element name for flash errors -

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', array(
    'authorize'=> 'Controller',
    'flash' => array(
        'element' => 'error'
    ),
    'authError' => 'Your session expired, please login again',
    'logoutRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'prefix' => false
     )
));
```

and error.ctp at - \src\Template\Element\Flash\error.ctp